# 301 redirect only on specific url whilst using seo friendly rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

I have a new website that is linked to from many places but the structure of the sitemap has changed. I need to redirect some old urls to the relevant new one.

The site also needs to keep its seo friendly url writing.

I have this in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase  /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(csr|quality|schools|project_management|third_sector|nhs|about)$


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(csr|quality|schools|project_management|third_sector|nhs|about)$ /about-us [L,R=301] 

</IfModule>
```

Going to /about redirects to /about-us (which is great), and going to /quality also redirects to /about-us (which is correct) too. However, going to /nhs or /schools (for instance) gives a 404. Why is this?

Any help will be appreciated.

[EDIT]

Removed [L] and it started working. Thanks

Comment: I tried running these rules under WAMP, and they all worked fine, including nhs and schools.  Are you using a CMS?  if so what CMS?

Comment: Using Conrete5 - I have it working now thanks.

Comment: Can you post the solution here for other people looking for the answer to this question?

Comment: I removed the L from the directive.

Comment: @beingalex -- Glad it's all set.  If you copy your answer and create it as an actual answer (not just a comment), then you can accept it (your own answer) so people will know it's answered :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's probably because your `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]` has an [L] flag (which means last.).

If the conditions are met for the first rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]` Apache will stop executing the other rules.

Try removing the `[L]`